# How to force Group for new folders IN new folders with SFTP Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sftp

I'm running into this issue where I use `g+s` and a `chgrp` to set the group, but when I create a new file or folder in a new directory, it doesn't inherit the group.

For example:

1. `/dir1` has `g+s` and a chgrp
2. Create `/dir1/dir2` on sftp
3. Make a file in `/dir1/dir2` with sftp.

`/dir1/dir2/file` will not inherit `/dir1`'s group as set with `g+s`.

I am using OpenBSD with Ubuntu 20.04